# Why `&{ "main::test" }` was not called?

Tags: perl

I know that `&` is an old syntax to call subroutines:

```perl
sub test { die 'xx' };

&{ "main::test" };
OUTPUT:
xx at main.pl line 1.
```

But why subroutine is not called when I use `defined &{ "main::test" }`?

```perl
sub test { die 'xx' };

print defined &{ "main::test" };
OUTPUT:
1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documented in [perlsub](http://p3rl.org/perlsub):

> A subroutine may be called using an explicit `&` prefix. The `&` is
> optional in modern Perl, as are parentheses if the subroutine has been
> predeclared. The `&` is not optional when just naming the subroutine, such
> as when it's used as an argument to [defined](http://p3rl.org/defined)() or [undef](http://p3rl.org/undef)(). Nor is it
> optional when you want to do an indirect subroutine call with a subroutine
> name or reference using the `&$subref()` or `&{$subref}()` constructs,
> although the `$subref->()` notation solves that problem. See [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref) for
> more about all that.

Under [defined](http://p3rl.org/defined), you can find (and similarly under [undef](http://p3rl.org/undef) and [exists](http://p3rl.org/exists)):

> You may also use `defined(&func)` to check whether subroutine func has ever been defined.

The parentheses after `defined` are optional (similarly to those after a predeclared sub). See [perlfunc](http://p3rl.org/perlfunc) for details.

Comment: Same for `exists`

Comment: Thank you. But you answer is not so clear. I think it will be more clear if you provide documentation of `define: You may also use defined(&func) to check whether subroutine func has ever been defined. ` and explicitly say: this is special syntax when used with `define`. Thank you.